# Auto-globalization of .net controls

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, globalization

Okay, I have hundreds of .net controls with `text` attributes that needs to be globalized. Is there a tool (VS or 3rd party) that can make my life easier? Im already using ReSharper on my C#, and VS on plain HTML text. Very neat.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking to extract the text to Local Resource files you can do that by choosing the aspx page and then Tools -> Generate Local Resource.

Comment: Yes im aware of that, but im looking for a "Generate Global Resource" :)

Answer (score 1):

Some years ago, I started developing a [tool to edit .RESX files from multiple languages inside one grid](http://www.zeta-resource-editor.com) to make translation easier. I'm still actively developing the tool (Freeware, BTW) and using it extensively for my own projects, too.

I'm not 100% sure that with "globalization" you refer to translation, though.

Comment: Very nice tool indeed. But thats not exactly what im looking for. Basicly im looking for a tool that can replace the static string in the Text attributes of the controls with a <%$ Resources: Random, randomname %> and ofcourse create the resx file if needed. a "Move to resources" function.